Why can't use numactl cmd to bind the process in container on specific cpu cores/mem
i use cmd "kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -n openfaas-fn -- /bin/sh" to build a shell process in a pod and want to bind this process on specific cpu core and mem node.
Then i use cmd "docker container top " to get the processid of "/bin/sh", which is 3714889 ,but when i run cmd "numactl --physcpubind=0 --membind=1 3714889", it shows "numactl: execution of `3714889': No such file or directory".
what's more, i thought the system can't see process in container because i can't see the result of the cmd "top | grep 3714889" ,but i can see the result of cmd"sudo cat /proc/3714889/status"
so how to bind the process in container(build via docker runtime) of pod on specfic cpu cores or mem node? then the process or conatiner can still be managed by this pod.
